# Cook image-fsl-qt5 of yocto on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: yocto, bitbake

[error we getting after bitbake-fsl-image-qt5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ207.png)
**strong text**We are trying to cook image-fsl-qt5 of Yocto and we are getting one error and unable to fix. I have Ubuntu 18.04.

we are installing yocto image for var-som-mx6 hardware to flash. we installed all packages but while doing bitbake command we are one error as in picture. We are unable to get hold of that.

[packages for yocto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OssEi.png)

[Download Yocto Fido for i.MX6 Freescale source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UqVj.png)

[Download Yocto Fido i.MX6 with Meta Variscite VAR-SOM-MX6 support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vNQN.png)

[Setup and build Yocto QT5/Embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNm2i.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
 As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
 See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Just a guess, as I cannot spot any meaningful image which shows an error; fido is massively outdated and has a high chance of not building on a recent distribution. Either have your supplier provide something that is not more than 4 years old, or try to build on something like Ubuntu 14.04. Maybe a dicker container can help you there.